# Function in the Fourier domain of a low-pass filter

Tags: lowpass-filter, frequency-response

I have to represent a low-pass filter in the Fourier domain having a cut-off frequency of $f_c={3}\ kHz$.

Could **all** low-pass filters could be represented with this function: $H(f)=\frac{1}{1+j\left(\frac{f}{f_c}\right)}$?

If so, my filter could be represented with this function: $H(f)=\frac{1}{1+j\left(\frac{f}{3*10^3}\right)}$. Is this correct?

Comment: "right or not?"  **Not!** What would the answer be if $f_c = 3$ Hz? What would the answer be if $f_c = 3$ rad/s ? Does the prefix "k" to "Hz" have any meaning?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I use $Hz$ as unit of measure for frequency.

Comment: I repeat: Does the prefix "k" to "Hz" have any meaning?

Comment: yes it means ${3}\ kHz = 3 * 10^3 Hz$

Comment: -2 seems a little harsh.  Why the minus votes?

Answer (score 6):

Not right. Your basic assumption that **all** lowpass filters can be represent through your formula is wrong. What you have is a first order IIR low pass but there are many more options for a low pass filter, such as higher order IIR filter of different types (butterworth, bessel, chebycheff 1+2, elliptic) and plus various FIR filters as well.